# why nodejs cannot close tcp connection？

Tags: node.js, http, tcp, keep-alive

[image]
[image]

this is my client.js code

```
const http = require('http')
const axios = require('axios')

http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true
http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets = 700

const test = async () => {
  const ret = await axios.post('http://localhost:9000/test')
  console.log('============ret', ret)
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}

test()
```

this is my server.js code.

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')

// set globalAgent
http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true
http.globalAgent.maxFreeSockets = 700

const PORT = 9000
const app = express()

app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hello')
})

// start server
const server = app.listen(PORT)

server.keepAliveTimeout = 60 * 1000
```

this is package.json，rely on axios@0.26.1 express@4.17.3

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.17.3"
  }
}
```

nodejs version v16.13.0

Wireshark version 3.6.3

my expected is

[image]

// 2022-04-08 update

[the clinic analyse result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4omOf.png)

Comment: Your client JS code is blocking the event loop with your `for` loop.  Why are you doing that?  That is likely preventing timely processing of the TCP connection handling.  Blocking the event loop has negative consequences in either client or server Javscript code.

Comment: @jfriend00 I originally wanted to test the mechanism of global agent. In order not to let the process exit, I used the for loop. But how to prove that the result is caused by the blocking of EventLoop? After all, the client send a ack packet.

Comment: If you just use `setTimeout()` set for a however long you want, that will keep nodejs from exiting until the timer fires, but leave the event loop free.  Raw CPU-intensive loops like that are never a good idea in the main nodejs thread because it needs the event loop available.  You can do that in a WorkerThread if you need to do CPU-intensive work.  I don't really understand what issue you're looking in your screenshots so can't comment on that.  I just know that blocking the event loop generally leads to problems so better to not do it.

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right，3q